# Echo a specific value from a multidimensional array using the Language class in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization

I'm having a confusion in Codeigniter and the Language Class. I'm using a library developed by Jerome Jaglale about Internationalization. The question might sound silly but if I have a multidimensional array stored in a language file, how can I load a specific array value in my view? Say in my controller I have

```
class Statics extends CI_Controller {

 public function index($page = 'home')
 { 
  // load language file
  $this->lang->load($page);
  $this->load->view($page);
 }
}
```

And then in my language file

```
$lang = array(   
 'description'   => array(     
    'main'  => 'Convallis habitant ultrices torquent consectetur sagittis eget metus magna elit fermentum diam tortor ad viverra nec consectetur id ac aliquam hac lobortis malesuada elit, elementum mollis tempor aliquam per nulla ipsum. Molestie non elit nec ante leo nam hendrerit aenean mauris aenean iaculis fringilla.',
    'secondary'  => 'Convallis habitant ultrices torquent consectetur sagittis eget metus magna elit fermentum diam tortor ad viverra nec consectetur id ac aliquam hac lobortis malesuada elit, elementum mollis tempor aliquam per nulla ipsum. Molestie non elit nec ante leo nam hendrerit aenean mauris aenean iaculis fringilla.',
)

 );
```

How can I echo 'main'? I've tried the following to no avail.

```
<p><?php echo lang('description.main')?></p>

<!-- I know this is wrong but tried it anyway -->
<p><?php echo lang('home.description.main')?></p> 
<p><?php echo lang('lang.description.main')?></p>
```

Please note that my program was tested successfully if I have something like $lang['description.main'] = 'text here...'. For me it would be better to have all my data in a mutlidimensional array instead, something similar to the array above.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe `echo lang('description')['main'];` or `echo lang('homedescription')['main'];` ?

Answer (score 2):

Very good question, but this might Help:
In you lang file:

```
$lang['description']['main'] = 'Convallis habitant ultrices torquent consectetur sagittis eget metus magna elit fermentum diam tortor ad viverra nec consectetur id ac aliquam hac lobortis malesuada elit, elementum mollis tempor aliquam per nulla ipsum. Molestie non elit nec ante leo nam hendrerit aenean mauris aenean iaculis fringilla.';
$lang['description']['secondary'] = 'Convallis habitant ultrices torquent consectetur sagittis eget metus magna elit fermentum diam tortor ad viverra nec consectetur id ac aliquam hac lobortis malesuada elit, elementum mollis tempor aliquam per nulla ipsum. Molestie non elit nec ante leo nam hendrerit aenean mauris aenean iaculis fringilla.';
```

or :

```
$lang = array(   
   'description'   => array(     
      'main'  => 'Convallis habitant ultrices torquent consectetur sagittis eget metus magna elit fermentum diam tortor ad viverra nec consectetur id ac aliquam hac lobortis malesuada elit, elementum mollis tempor aliquam per nulla ipsum. Molestie non elit nec ante leo nam hendrerit aenean mauris aenean iaculis fringilla.',
      'secondary'  => 'Convallis habitant ultrices torquent consectetur sagittis eget metus magna elit fermentum diam tortor ad viverra nec consectetur id ac aliquam hac lobortis malesuada elit, elementum mollis tempor aliquam per nulla ipsum. Molestie non elit nec ante leo nam hendrerit aenean mauris aenean iaculis fringilla.',
   )  
);
```

and to access either of them:

```
foreach ($this->lang->line('description') as $desc => $val)
{
    echo $desc . " : " . $val . "<br />";
}
```

But the for not array types following works fine!

```
echo $this->lang->line('description')['main'];
```

Comment: Reza,
Thanks for your suggestion.What I'm actually trying to accomplish is to have all my data in a single array of the format

<code>
$lang = array(   
  'description'   => array (     
      'main'      => 'value',
      'secondary' => value'));
</code>

The reason is because I don't want to be typing "$lang[][]" for every single value in my array. I also want to be able to spot my array values quickly when scanning through my lang file, that is, considering my array is huge, indenting it would be perfect for that purpose (just like the example above).

Comment: From your suggestions I noticed that I'm not very familiar with the syntax below, the doubt is specifically about the () followed immediately by []. I tried the line in my code and I get a syntax error.

<code>
echo $this->lang->line('description')['main'];
</code>

So basically I have two questions: 
1. Would it be possible to have my array the way I want, or do I necessarily have to set my values individually like $lang[][] ?
2. If the previous is yes, how do I print 'main', for example?

Comment: I used to use Smarty before and maybe my whole confusion is because in Smarty I would simply do {$lang.description.main}, now back to PHP without a template engine I realize I have some confusions.